# Using a joystick or gamepad to traverse through scene2d menu

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm wondering how I can add support easily to traverse my scene2d menus (tables) with LibGDX using a joystick, gamepad or keyboard keys.

Does anyone know how it should be done?

Comment: A ScrollPane that you move around while processing the input would be a great way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring the concept of focus in your menu, rest is easy. (Just like old video games)

1. Maintain a focus variable in your menu.
2. Draw the menu-item in focus differently (Maybe an additional border).
3. Handle key events properly to update value of focus.

Hope this helps.